# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kestrel-http-server

One customer keeps getting this error and I think it is due to a slow connection/latency problem but wondering if anyone else has run into this.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id “0HLP5AO39QCJI”, Request id “0HLP5AO39QCJI:00000017”: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(SocketError e)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.ProcessReceives()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.PumpAsync()
at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: which asp.net core runtime version you are using?

Comment: asp.net core 2.2.4.